# Install proxmox 4.1 on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, proxmox

I installed proxmox 4.1 on virtual box and after installationI received the following :

**welcome to the proxmox virtual environment.please use your web browser to configure this server - connect to:**

https://192.168.56.101:8006

but while trying this https://192.168.56.101:8006 in the browser it is not working 
can someone advice !

Comment: use http, not https, you don't have a valid certificate yet

Comment: check that the firewall is not disallowing that access to 8006

Comment: Are your virtual machine and browser on the same network?
By default VB will create a separate network for each VM.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the VirtualBox Machine Network Adapter is in Bridge Mode. And check that your host and the vm are in the same IP rank (Ex: Windows: 192.168.1.50 & Proxmox: 192.168.1.70)

Answer (score 0):

Your network adapter in VirtualBox has been set to host-only. If you want to connect to it with your PC you'd better set-up bridged networking.

Also when you've did that, change your `/etc/hosts` file on the Proxmox hosts so that it won't give you any errors while setting up the webserver or any optional clusters.

Comment: Add some more details

Comment: When you'll bridge it, you have a dedicated IP to your router and than it would also be accesible from other PCs in the same network. When you only have it set-up host-only you have to add NAT network to download any updates to have it automatically set-up right.